# switching ApplicationBarIcon iconuri on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have in my windows phone application an applicationBar that contains 2 appbariconbutton:

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="appbar_button1" IconUri="/Images/appbar_im1_selected.png" Text="im1" Click="appbar_button1_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="appbar_button2" IconUri="/Images/appbar_im2.png" Text="im2" Click="appbar_button2_Click" />

    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

My need is to change the iconUri of 2 appbariconbutton like this

```
    private void appbar_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //Switch the iconuri of appbar_button1 from /Images/appbar_im1_selected.png to /Images/appbar_im1.png
//Switch the iconuri of appbar_button2 from /Images/appbar_im2.png to /Images/appbar_im1_selected.png
        }
```

How can do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the IconUri of the icon

```
private void appbar_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((ApplicationBarIconButton)this.ApplicationBar.Buttons[0]).IconUri = new Uri("/Images/appbar_im1.png", UriKind.Relative);
    ((ApplicationBarIconButton)this.ApplicationBar.Buttons[1]).IconUri = new Uri("/Images/appbar_im1_selected.png", UriKind.Relative);
}
```